# Issue with readHTMLtable

Tags: html, xml, r, web-scraping

Does anyone know why `readHTMLtable` doesn't seem to be able to get the main table off this website?  It gets 16 tables but they are incomprehensible.

```
library('RCurl')
library('XML')
url.nsf<-"http://www.nsf.gov/awardsearch/showAward?AWD_ID=0114304"
html.nsf<-getURL(url.nsf)
tables.nsf<-readHTMLTable(html.nsf)
```

I have not used the **XML** package in a while and was never very good with html.

Comment: What is incomprehensible? It looks like `tables.nsf[[9]]` is what you want. If it isn't explain in more detail your intended result.

Comment: agreed @Thomas. Here it is: `tables.nsf[[9]][-seq(1, nrow(tables.nsf[[9]]), 2), ]`

Comment: @Thomas: You are right.  I am not sure what was wrong earlier but tables.nsf[[9]] was not returning what I expected.  I just retried and it works fine.  Apologies and thank you.